# C# SecurityToken exists in multiple

Tags: c#, sts

I'm specifying the exact class to use, but Visual Studio is telling me that the method also exists in another class.

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken token = null;
```

I don't understand why VS wouldn't just use the exact class that I specified.

How do I get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: Could be a weird Visual Studio thing, have you tried closing and reopening VS?

Comment: Yeah I did that

Comment: I also just tried deleting the .suo file and re-opening.

Comment: "I don't understand why VS wouldn't just use the exact class that I specified." - on the contrary: it **is** using the exact class you specified, the problem is both assemblies (`System.IdentityModel.dll` and `System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll` **both** have their own separate classes with the exact same namespace+name), this suggests you're using very incompatible assemblies. Given that `System.ServiceModel` is from WCF I'm guessing you're working on a project being migrated from .NET Framework to .NET Core or .NET 5+ perhaps? If so, then (for everyone's sake) just ditch WCF entirely.

Comment: @bagofmilk Now, repeat after me: "I will never use WCF ever again."